# Horizontal Alignment ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, alignment, listviewitem

I need to put my listviewitems Horizontally, but I can't find the way, so far I tried this:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cells, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellGroupTemplate}"
                        Background="{StaticResource EnvLayout}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

my items are other UI controls, with their viewmodel attached

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CellItemViewModel}" x:Key="CellGroupTemplate">
        <vw:CellItemView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Can someone tell me how to put each Element (datatemplate) next to the other

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom items panel for your *ListView*:

```
 <ListView>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 </ListView>
```